# Listview is not updated automatically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a listview that shows search results of a search box. When window is loaded, all data from database displays in listview - "this is good".

But when I search for thing, variable in view model changes and stores the new data but listview doesn't display new data from variable.

XAML code for listview

```
<ListView x:Name="itemsListView" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Rows, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
              Grid.Row="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              Margin="40,10,40,10"
              FlowDirection="RightToLeft" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedIndex="1">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BankName}" 
                            Width="250"
                            Header="bank name"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Credit}" 
                            Header="credit"
                            Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsActive}" 
                            Header="statue"
                            Width="100"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Notes}" 
                            Header="notes"
                            Width="230"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

View model code

```
class BanksVM 
{
    private ObservableCollection<BanksListVM> m_Rows;

    public ObservableCollection<BanksListVM> Rows
    {
        get { return m_Rows; }
        set { m_Rows = value; }
    }

    private string _BanksSearchBox;

    public string BanksSearchBox
    {
        get { return _BanksSearchBox; }
        set {
            _BanksSearchBox = value;
            SearchInBanksMethod();
        }
    }

    //set all data to listview
    public BanksVM()
    {
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<BanksListVM>();
        Rows.Clear();

        List < Banks > bankslist = new List<Banks>();
        Banks banks = new Banks();
        bankslist = banks.GetAllBanks();

        foreach (Banks b in bankslist)
        {
            string IsActive = "";

            if (b.IsActive == true)
                IsActive = "open";
            else
                IsActive = "closed";

            Rows.Add(new BanksListVM
            {
                ID = b.ID,
                BankName = b.BankName,
                IsActive = IsActive,
                Credit = b.Credit,
                Notes = b.Notes
            });
        }
    }

    // refresh listview method
    public void SearchInBanksMethod() { 
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<BanksListVM>();
        Rows.Clear();

        List<Banks> bankslist = new List<Banks>();
        search Search = new search();
        bankslist = Search.SearchInBanks(_BanksSearchBox);

        foreach (Banks b in bankslist)
        {
            string IsActive = "";

            if (b.IsActive == true)
                IsActive = "open";
            else
                IsActive = "closed";

            Rows.Add(new BanksListVM
            {
                ID = b.ID,
                BankName = b.BankName,
                IsActive = IsActive,
                Credit = b.Credit,
                Notes = b.Notes
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to clear the Rows Collection if you instantiate it with new. Only use "clear" in the "SearchInBanksMethod" instead of assigning a new object. Also make sure that BanksVM inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: OK, but this is not solving the problem

Comment: That should solve the problem. I recommend to use

    public ObservableCollection<BanksListVM> Rows { get; set; } = new ...();

In this case you don't even have to set it in the constructor.

Comment: there is no problem in storing data in Row . the problem is display it again in the listview

Comment: I do understand your problem. I made an answer to make things more clear.

Comment: The problem in binding data for the second time. that is all

Comment: In the XAML you bind to "Rows". While you reinitialize Rows code behind after the XAML has been loaded, the binding to the ListView gets lost. Therefore, it won't be updated anymore. If I interpret your question wrong,  more detailed information would help.

Comment: you now understood me :) . how can i bind data again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reassigning the ObservableCollection, the Binding isn't notified about the new property value.

In the `SearchInBanksMethod`, remove

```
Rows = new ObservableCollection<BanksListVM>();
```

and only use

```
Rows.Clear();
```